# Configure Vim to use Xiki

Tags: vim, xiki

I have installed xiki as per the instructions in https://github.com/trogdoro/xiki. I have read that Xiki provides partial support for Vi. I want to know how to setup Vim with Xiki. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Where does it say that Xiki has support for Vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having no experience with xiki, I just googled this: https://github.com/trogdoro/xiki/tree/master/etc/vim. And here is some status report: https://github.com/trogdoro/xiki/blob/master/etc/vim/vim_status.notes. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

In searching for the answer to this, I encountered this question. I have now found it on my own:
The vim folder got moved. Here is the folder for vim in the Xiki github:
https://github.com/trogdoro/xiki/tree/master/misc/vim
here is the status report:
https://github.com/trogdoro/xiki/blob/master/misc/vim/vim_status.notes
and here is how it says to enable Xiki in Vim:

> ```
> - 1) Add this line, and then restart vim   
> ~/.vimrc
>   | let $XIKI_DIR = "[xiki dir]"
>   | source [xiki dir]/etc/vim/xiki.vim
>
> - 2) Type "ip" on a blank line and double-click on it
> ```